# Problems with windows credentials IIS 10.0

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, iis

I have a **.NET core 3.1 razor pages** website. I'm using windows credentials (with Active directory) for **authentication** and I'm managing **authorization** using policies.
Using IIS express (*the one you use when developing is working ok. My username is displayed*)

Now I'm using the IIS manager to host this site using my machine IP, for example 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:portNumber'. This is loading if anonymous authentication is on, but if I include windows credentials it is failing.
I followed the guide from here --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
Basically I did what it is showed in the previous link. (*Created the web.config file and followed the steps listed there*)

*web.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The following error is showing up when I try to enter authentication option in IIS manager in my site.

*This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false"*
After hitting accept button the following table loads.

[image: error image 1]

And when I try to access the website, it is throwing
**Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error**

**Module: WindowsAuthenticationModule**

**Notification: AuthenticateRequest**

**source of config**

```
  <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
   **<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />** --> *this line is in red*
  </authentication>
```

Here I changed a couple of lines in *applicationhost.config* file.

```
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

I changed both lines from **Deny** to **Allow**. Restart, but it doesn't work.

I've activated some windows features too like the following
[image: windows features]

Comment: For security concerns, such settings can only be changed in `applicationHost.config`. Search for previous discussions and you can find tons of hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. I referred to this post [This configuration section cannot be used at this path - Windows 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011046/this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-windows-2016)

I setted the following entries in the file located in
`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

```
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

I mistakenly edited the `applicationHost.config` located in `IISExpress` in my documents folder. That's why this wasn't working.